# ViewPagerAdapter instantiateItem method not return any value

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-view

I wasted my whole day to find solution how viewpagerAdapter works? I googled lot but i couldnt able to find. Actually this is my problem

In MainActivity :

```
adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(this,R.layout.your_custom_xml, Arrayvalue);
pager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

In PagerAdapterClass :

```
public MyPagerAdapter(Context context, List<String> arrayvalue) {
// TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
super();

    this.context = context;
    this.objects = arrayvalue;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
   return objects.size();
}    

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(View convertView, int position) {

LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
          context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = convertView;
    v = inflater.inflate(your_custom_xml, null);

    title = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tv_search_title);

    String str  = objects.get(position);
    title.setText(str.indexOf(position));

    return v;
}
```

What am getting only blank screen. Where am going wrong??

I would appreciate any help

Comment: Please show more code from your adapter class.

Comment: does Arrayvalue contain something? Did you override getCount in your custom adapter?

Comment: see my edited question buddies